# Cannot Drop the unmannaged Delta lake table through pyspark code

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, drop-table, dbutils

I am trying to drop a unmanaged table but it only drops its metadata. I am using the following Code in Databricks

```
spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS default.StoresSales")
dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/mnt/ext_source/sparkDeltaTables/default.StoresSales",True)
```

Tried True and False both options but nothing works with the files at located on the Storage. I need to manually delete the files.

The command gives the following Output:
**java.io.IOException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This operation is not permitted on a non-empty directory.**

Comment: which databricks are you using aws or azure?

Comment: What is the output when you ran above two commands

Comment: I am using the Azure.

Comment: java.io.IOException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This operation is not permitted on a non-empty directory.

Comment: By any chance would this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60220441/1100699