# "DROP TABLE mytable PURGE" raises SparkUnsupportedOperationException

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-storage, databricks-sql

Using Spark 3.5.0 on an existing delta-table in Databricks:

```
%sql
DROP TABLE mytable PURGE


SparkUnsupportedOperationException: DROP TABLE ... PURGE.
```

while it works well without the purge:

```
%sql
DROP TABLE mytable


OK.
```

Checking the file system I realise the data is still there. I want to delete it when deleting the table like described in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-drop-table.html#parameter), but it doesn't work.

1. Any ideas why this does happen?
2. Any ideas how else to delete the data on the filesystem (Azure storage) separately?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59042576/3104974) for the 2nd question (in python):

```
dbutils.fs.rm('abfss://path/to/external/mytable', recurse=True)
```

or

```
%fs
rm abfss://path/to/external/mytable
```

And maybe the PURGE doesn't work since the table is on an external storage, so the DROP TABLE and the PURGE probably must be done separately.